# Discord.py not seeing updates to User/Member roles

Tags: discord.py

When running a Discord bot using discord.py, if a user's roles are edited, the information can't be see by the bot. For example:

1:
User A (not in role R) uses the "join" command. Bot adds user to R.

User A (now in role R) uses the "leave" command. Bot thinks that the user isn't in R and complains.

2:
User A (in role R) uses the "leave" command. Bot removes user from R

User A (not in role R) uses the "join" command. Bot thinks the user is in R already and complains.

If I use a debugger and inspect the given user, it appears that the role never gets added/removed. *The role change does appear within Discord itself though.* Restarting the bot allows one update again before it breaks, so it makes me think that something isn't updating when the user's roles change.

The code is pretty straightforward too:

```
async def giveRole(user, wantedRole, message):
    role = getRoleToAdd(wantedRole) # some logic to get the role to leave/join, verified to work

    if role in user.roles:
        await message.channel.send("You've already joined that role")

    else:
        await user.add_roles(role)
```

The "leave" logic is just flipped, using user.remove_roles(role) instead.

Comment: Have you upgraded discord.py to 1.5 and added `intents`?

Comment: It occurred to me to use intents, but not that I'm a dummy and have an out-of-date Discord.py. I'll try updating and starting from there, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While you do have to update and add the default intents, I don't think you need `intents.members` for your usecase.

I did have a similar Issue and while I had `Intents.members` enabled all along, my issue was that I reused the same member object to check roles before and after assigning new ones.

```
roles_before = [role.name for role in updated_roles_member.roles]
await assignRolesToUser(roleList, mentioned_user, message.guild)
updated_roles_member = await mentioned_user.guild.fetch_member(mentioned_user.id)
roles_now = [role.name for role in updated_roles_member.roles]
```

This gave me the new list of roles